# Errors in VHDL code

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, error, vlsi, modelsim

The VHDL code was written by me for a 4-bit PIPO DFF register. I have been encountering some errors when i did so. Kindly check the code and errors below.

```
Code:
1.library ieee;
2.use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
3.
4.entity paralleldreg is port
5. (  
6.       load,reset,clk : in std_logic_vector;
7.                    d : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
8.                    q : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
9.  
10.  );
11. end paralleldreg;
12.
13. architecture dreg of paralleldreg is 
14. begin
15. shifting : process(clk,reset,load)
16. begin 
17.     if(reset ='0') then q <= "0000";    
18.     
19.        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then 
20.        if(load='1') then q<=d;
21.        end if;
22.    
23.     end if;
24. end process shifting;
25. end architecture dreg;
```

Errors :

1. Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/dregister.vhd(18): No feasible entries for subprogram "rising_edge".
2. Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/dregister.vhd(19): near "=": syntax error
3. Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/dregister.vhd(23): VHDL Compiler exiting

Comment: do you have a question of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entity signals `clk`, `load` and `reset` should be of type `std_logic`.
You cannot apply a `rising_edge` detection on a `std_logic_vector`.

Further, the `load` signal doesn't have to be in your sensitivity list. The sensitivity list holds the signals that should cause a re-elaboration of your process but `q` is not elaborated when `load` changes but only on the rising edge of `clk`.

Answer (score 0):

## Since VHDL-2008

There is no need for sensitivity lists. They have been replaced with the `all` keyword. It is supported by Modelsim, though not everyone is up-to-date. Sensitivity lists used to cause lots of bugs due to simulator-synthesis mismatches, but are now a thing of the past.

To enable VHDL-2008 in Modelsim, go to:

`Menu -> Compile -> Compile Options... -> VHDL tab -> Select "Use 1076-2008"`

[VHDL-2008](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4772740) – Status: Superceded by VHDL-2019

[VHDL-2019](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8938196) – Status: Active and Approved

```vhdl
shifting : process(all)
begin
    if not reset then
        q <= "0000";
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        if load then
            q <= d;
        end if;
    end if;
end process shifting;
```